# Can't load context from within IntelliJ when including external jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm working on a multi-module Spring Boot project that can use non-spring plugins. Plugins are loaded using `java.util.ServiceLoader`. They may use spring beans provided by a ContextBridge implementing `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware`. The end result looks like this:

```
app-folder/
  plugins/
    myplugin.jar
  myapplication.jar
  launcher-script.sh
```

The application and the plugins work as intended when started using the shell script:

```
java -Dloader.path=.,plugins -jar myapplication.jar "$@"
```

However, I can't figure out how to configure IntelliJ to start the application AND find the plugins so I would be able to debug more comfortably.

**I've tried the following approaches**

- Adding the `-Dloader.path` config to the launch configuration doesn't seem to work. I have tried both Appliaction and Spring Boot launch configurations. This didn't seem to do anything. It just loads the main application but no plugins.
- Adding the plugins through gradle:

  `compile fileTree(dir: 'dist/plugins', include: '**/*.jar')`

This does load the plugin but fails to load the context which I take from the error message I get:
`s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setMyService' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.myapp.MyService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

So I added bean dependencies to the code in order to force a certain order in which beans get initialized:

**Data-Access Module**

```
interface Myservice {
  ...
}

@Service
@Qualifier("MyServiceBean")
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  ...
}
```

**ContextBridge inside Plugin**

```
@Component
@DependsOn("MyService)
public class ContextBridgeImpl implements ContextBridge, ApplicationContextAware {
  ...
}
```

Then I get:

`Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'MyService' available`

What confuses me is the fact that everythings works when started from the console. Why not inside IntelliJ?

**Edit**
Screen shots showing launch configurations
[image: Launch configuration via shell script]
[image]

Comment: IntelliJ is probably running the project in the target folder in your project directory. You should try changing the working directory of your Spring Boot Run Debug Configuration to the one you launch the command line app from.

Comment: There is no target folder. Only out and build. Tried setting the working directory to build/classes/main. Same result: Everything ok with no plugins installed. NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when there are plugins around.

Comment: When launching from the command line, do you run the command from `build/classes/main`? If not, the Configuration working directory should point to the folder from you can successfully run the project via command line.

Comment: I have a gradle task that places all the assembled components including the shell script inside a `./dist` folder. Its a simple copy task. I then run it from there. What doesn't work is the "Spring Boot" type launch configuration as long as a plugin is present (found and loaded up to the point where a dependency would be injected).
The plugins import and process data from various sources. So, I can debug them using a dedicated main class. Just not when integrated into the main application.

Comment: Creating an IntelliJ debug configuration will provide the command line arguments for debugging. Including those arguments when i start the app via CL allows me to connect the IntelliJ debugger. YMMV.

Comment: @TheHeadRush I don't exactly understand what you mean. May I have missed some checkbox when I created the launch configuration? I have now created a small dummy plugin inside the main application, so I can at least debug the general mechanisms. I added some screen shots of how the launch configurations are configured.

Comment: I misspoke in my previously reply. You need a Remote configuration to connect to a JVM not managed by IntelliJ.